# Trouble using postgres sql in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 operating system and have recently installed postgres using the instructions given in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04.

However, when I tried to use postgres using

```
snowbell@snowbell-Aspire-4738Z:/var/www$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@snowbell-Aspire-4738Z:~$ psql
```

I got the following error message

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
postgres@snowbell-Aspire-4738Z:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

In order to get away with this error, I tried using

```
snowbell@snowbell-Aspire-4738Z:~$ sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1
```

As a result, I got the following error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any clues?

The output is as follows 
[image]

Here is the Sample_error file blissini

[image]

Comment: Can you post the output: of sudo netstat -lntp ?

Comment: see the snapshot for the output

Comment: Is postgresql running? Try `ps -ef | grep postgres`. If not, look into `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-*-main.log`for startup errors.

Comment: Yes, postgresql is working  Following is the output

Comment: snowbell@snowbell-Aspire-4738Z:~$ ps -ef | grep postgres
snowbell  5425  5411  0 19:49 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres

Comment: from the snapshot I see that your postgres server is not running, so you can't connect to it.
You can start the service with `sudo systemctl start postgresql.service`.

Comment: blissini,  i entered the command to start the postgresql service, still I am not able to log in to psql server....I have attached the snapshot by the name Sample_error...kindly see the post

Comment: Your postgres isn't running, co you can't connect. Check `systemctl status postgresql` or `journalct -u postgres` (or postgres error log within `/var/log`) for errors. And don't attach pictures, when you can just copy text.

Answer (score 2):

If you have exhausted what has been suggested in the comments then the error itself may be related to a misconfiguration of `postgresql`, which causes the server to crash before it starts.

I would suggest following these instructions:

1. Ensure that `postgresql` service is running, using `sudo service postgresql start`
2. Run `pg_lsclusters` from your terminal
3. Check what is the cluster you are running, the output should be something like:

> Version - Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory
>
> ```
> 9.6 ------- main -- 5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
> ```

4. Copy the info from the version and the cluster, and use like so:  `pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> start`, for example: `pg_ctlcluster 9.6 main start`
5. If something is wrong, then `postgresql` will generate a log, that can be accessed on `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-<version>-main.log`, for example:

> ```
> 2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-1] LOG: invalid authentication method "all" 
> 2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-2] CONTEXT: line 90 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf" 
> 2017-07-13 16:53:04 BRT [32176-3] FATAL: could not load pg_hba.conf
> ```

Whatever error the log gives you, fix it and restart postgresql service through:

`sudo service postgresql restart`